# Beginner: Unknown faces on Mesh

Tags: mesh, vertices, faces

Hopefully an easy solve. I've imported in an SVG and made it 3D, but I get these random faces that are appearing probably due to unnecessary vertices. How can I clean this up? I've tried using Dissolve but it seems to create more mess :S
You can see the mess [here](https://we.tl/xtNeoSDJsN) 
[image]

Comment: Go into edit mode, switch to edge selection, select the edge you don't want, and delete it.

Comment: It's this triangular shape you can see. I can't select anything for it - it has no edges!

Comment: Press Alt+H to unhide possibly hidden geometry. Go into face mode (Ctrl+F) and select the unwanted face.

Comment: Could you upload the offending file so we can take a look?

Comment: Thanks guys! Tried Alt+H but didn't do anything unfortunately. I have provided a link to the file in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will walk you through some steps in removing and adding faces with the letter **E**.

#### Modeling Resources

- [Selection Mode](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html#selection-mode)
- [Loop Select](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#select-loops)
- [Creating Faces](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/adding.html?highlight=make%20face#filling-faces)
- [Deletion Modes](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/deleting.html#delete)

---

1. Go into edit mode. Let's first delete all non manifold geometry. Deselect all with <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>. Press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to select non manifold geometry. Press <kbd>X</kbd> and choose vertices to delete the unnecessary vertices.
   [image]
2. Go into face selection mode. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>.
3. Select the large n-gon which causes the strange face. The select dot show its center. Delete it.
   [image]
4. Select the other problematic n-gons. Because some important vertices (marked red) are connected to only the face, deleting the face would be wrong, because these vertices would be deleted as well. Just delete the face with <kbd>X</kbd> > **Only Faces**.
   [image]
5. We want to connect the following vertices with an edge, but they're already overlapped by another edge and face.
   [image]
6. Hence, delete the faces and the overlapping edges first.
   [image] [image]
7. Now create the remaining face. Select multiple vertices, which you want to connect with a face with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + Rightclick. Then press <kbd>F</kbd> to make an edge / a face.
   [image]
8. To select the last edge loop, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> + rightclick on it.

Comment: Jaw drop! Thank you so much Leander. This is brilliant!!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the text tool in Blender to make the name. Make cuts where needed, then extrude the faces you want. It'll be a whole lot easier that sorting out this mess.

What you have there are ngons ( polys with more than 4 point ) that connect throughout the model. You can just delete and select them, but chances are you can just remake them easily.

Comment: It's an inherited vector, so there's no type. But, as you say, going forward it might be best to avoid this mess where there's potentially lots of anomalous vertices